# How to display Current Location ADDRESS in textbox?

Tags: android

I've created this Textbox, and a Button beside it. I've also linked this Button to a class which display a map with the longitude, latitude, a push pin etc. But i have a question, how do i make this textbox such that it auto generate the current location address ?

Answer (score 1):

hiii..

It's so simple if you already tracked the latitude and longitude of as in case of map view.

```
TextView myAddress = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myaddress);

       myLatitude.setText("Latitude: " + String.valueOf(LATITUDE));
       myLongitude.setText("Longitude: " + String.valueOf(LONGITUDE));

       Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.ENGLISH);

       try {
  List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(LATITUDE, LONGITUDE, 1);

  if(addresses != null) {
   Address returnedAddress = addresses.get(0);
   StringBuilder strReturnedAddress = new StringBuilder("Address:\n");
   for(int i=0; i<returnedAddress.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
    strReturnedAddress.append(returnedAddress.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n");
   }
   myAddress.setText(strReturnedAddress.toString());
  }
  else{
   myAddress.setText("No Address returned!");
  }
 } catch (IOException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
  myAddress.setText("Canont get Address!");
 }

   }
}
```